# eclipse delta pack vs eclipse runtime

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

Could you explain a difference between eclipse runtime and with eclipse deltapack?

I assume that eclipse runtime is a platform specific part of eclipse sdk, if so what then delta pack is for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delta pack is used to build RCP applications for a different target than the machine you are building on. In other words, it is useful when you want to build a project for multiple platforms.

Comment: Deltapack contains eclipse runtime for soma platform?